# FacebookActivity does not closed, when Chrome Tab has been used for login flow

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin

I am integrating Facebook Login to my project, with custom button.

Here is callback manager in `AuthActivity`

```
class AuthActivity : LocaleAwareCompatActivity(), BaseFragmentEvents {
private var navController: NavController? = null
private lateinit var binding: ActivityAuthBinding

lateinit var callbackManager: CallbackManager
```

Here is init method.

```
private fun initFacebook() {
    FacebookSdk.setClientToken(getString(R.string.facebook_app_id))
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(applicationContext)
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        FacebookSdk.setIsDebugEnabled(true)
        FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS)
    }
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
}
```

Here is onActivityResult in `AuthActivity`

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

And Here is the action in `Fragment` when custom Login button clicked

```
 private fun startFacebookFlow() {
        (activity as? AuthActivity)?.callbackManager?.let { callbackManager ->
            LoginManager.getInstance()
                .logInWithReadPermissions(this, callbackManager, listOf("email"))
        }
    }

private fun registerFacebookFlow() {
    (activity as? AuthActivity)?.callbackManager?.let { callbackManager ->
        LoginManager.getInstance()
            .registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
                override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult) {
                    showLoading()
                    initialViewModel.checkSocialAccount(
                        SocialData(
                            null,
                            token = result.accessToken.token,
                            null, null, null,
                            socialType = FACEBOOK
                        )
                    )
                }

                override fun onCancel() {
                    hideLoading()
                }

                override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
                    hideLoading()
                    if (error is FacebookAuthorizationException) {
                        if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()
                            startFacebookFlow()
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Everything works correctly when there is a facebook app, but when chrome tab is opened, in both cases when user closes or logins with the credentials, only `CustomTabActivity` and `CustomTabMainActivity` are getting closed, but the main `FacbookActivity` does not get closed, and only after back swipe it getting closed.

Answer (score 1):

OK, seems like problem is related to `androidx.activity:activity` version, with `1.5.1` it wont work, forcing it to be `1.5.0` fix it.

Check this issue.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/1100